# num2hex vs dec2hex in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hex

I don't understand the difference between `hex2dec` and `hex2num` and their opposites in MATLAB.

Say I had a hex value, 3FD3B502C055FE00. When I use `hex2dec`, I get  4.5992e+018
. When I use `hex2num`, I get  0.3079. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions work very differently, as you noticed. `hex2dec` converts a hexadecimal string to a floating-point number by raw byte conversion, and I think you found that this works as you were expecting. However, `hex2num` converts a hexadecimal string to its *IEEE double-precision* representation.

The [IEEE 754 double precision standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) calls for a one-bit sign, a 11-bit exponent, and a 52-bit fraction. So `hex2num` parses the hexadecimal in this format, yielding a very different result from `hex2dec`.

Comment: Is there a way to convert from say, a double to this IEEE double precision standard in C? I'm trying to convert some MATLAB code to C.

Comment: @xiongtx: That would be worthy of another question.

Answer (score 1):

hex2dec -
Convert hexadecimal number string to decimal number

Description
d = hex2dec('hex_value') converts hex_value to its floating-point integer representation. The argument hex_value is a hexadecimal integer stored in a MATLAB string. **The value of hex_value must be smaller than hexadecimal 10,000,000,000,000.**

If hex_value is a character array, each row is interpreted as a hexadecimal string.

hex2num -
Convert hexadecimal number string to double-precision number

Description
n = hex2num(S), where S is a 16 character string representing a hexadecimal number, returns the IEEE® double-precision floating-point number n that it represents. Fewer than 16 characters are padded on the right with zeros. If S is a character array, each row is interpreted as a double-precision number.

NaNs, infinities and denorms are handled correctly.

Knowing that 3FD3B502C055FE00 is bigger than (10,000,000,000,000)16, out of range.